# Is it possible to create a LAN-only email system or some other kind of messaging system?

Tags: networking, local, alert

I'm asking because I have a few servers set up on my LAN, a storage server, two web servers a game server and a Pi-Hole server.

I've tried to create my own email server but I just couldn't get it to work. More than anything this system would just be so that my servers can send me alerts if they run low on space or need critical security updates, etc. I often forget to check them manually and it seems I'm just tempting fate.

Is there any way I can rig up a system that allows my servers to send me some kind of alert without needing to faff with creating a fully-fledged email system? Thanks.

Comment: Why not just set up the servers to send the email via a script? Create a separate email account that will only be used to send mail and use `postfix` or `ssmtp` to send the alerts _(there are terminal-based message systems, but the easiest way I've found to do this is the aforementioned)_. For example, [this](https://github.com/JW0914/Wikis/blob/master/Scripts%2BConfigs/OpenWrt/First-Run.sh) is a script I built for OpenWrt that uses `ssmtp`, whereas [this](https://github.com/JW0914/FreeNAS-Report/blob/master/custom-report.sh) is one I use on my FreeNAS server that uses `sendmail`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a mixed environment, that is, Windows and/or Mac in addition to our Linux machine(s), I would suggest looking at [BeeBeep](https://www.beebeep.net/). It's currently free, open source, and intended to be secure using AES (flaws may exist, but at least they try!). Also, it does not require a central server.

LAN Messenger is no longer free and no longer available for Linux :(.

Unless you are using a Pi Zero variant for your Pi-Hole, I'll bet it could also serve as a messaging server should you choose a messaging-only solution that requires a central server.